# Create Azure Database for PostgreSQL with Initialization Script for schema, tables, roles, etc in Terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-postgresql

I have created the Azure Postgre SQL server and DB using terraform.
Now I need to deploy the table and fields(schema).
Can this be done through terraform or we need different set of tools? eg: Azure CLI to deploy the tables?

I am looking for similar feature as below(Create Azure Database for PostgreSQL with Initialization Script) using terraform and other tools but not ARM Template given this example.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-postgresql/tree/master/arm-templates/ExampleWithStartupScript

Answer (score 0):

You may consider schema management tools such as [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/get-started/quickstart) which allow you to manage all database scripts as code which can be used to reliably apply changes to database instances across all your environments. If you are using CI/CD tools then it can be incorporated into the "deploy" phase of your database project.

Here's one way to accomplish schema management. I'm going to assume you have your source code in GitHub and therefore will use GitHub Actions to trigger the database "deployment"

1. Create a changelog.xml file in your repo whose contents is as follows. (*Personally, I recommend creating a separate project for your database and maintaining it like any other python, java, node, etc. project that makes up your system rather than colocating them. It's much cleaner that way*)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.23.xsd">

    <includeAll path="scripts" />
</databaseChangeLog>
```

2. Create a scripts folder in your repository and add DML/DDL using a naming scheme that identifies the order in which to apply them. e.g.
   `scripts/001_customer_table.sql` creates a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50)
);
```

`scripts/002_add_address_table.sql` adds a new table and modifies an existing table

```sql
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    address_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    street VARCHAR(100),
    city VARCHAR(50),
    state VARCHAR(50),
    country VARCHAR(50),
    postal_code VARCHAR(20)
);

ALTER TABLE customers
ADD COLUMN address_id INT,
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_address
    FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
    REFERENCES addresses(address_id);
```

3. Define the following GitHub repository secrets

| Secret Name | Sample value |
| --- | --- |
| DB_URL | jdbc:postgresql://mydbserver.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/mycoooldb&sslmode=require |
| DB_LOGIN | cheeky_monkey |
| DB_PASSWORD | s3cr3tP@55w0rd |

4. Now create a GitHub Action that uses the liquibase action to perform the deployment. GitHub actions live in `.github/workflows` so we will create `.github/workflows/dbdeploy.yml` whose contents are below.

```yaml
name: Database Schema Setup

on:
  push: 
    branches: master

  workflow_dispatch: # Manual trigger

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  deploy-mti-saps-master-db-action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:  
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Run Liquibase update on postgres db
      uses: liquibase-github-actions/update@v4.25.0
      with:
        changelogFile: changelog.xml
        url: ${{ secrets.DB_URL }}
        username: ${{ secrets.DB_LOGIN }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
```

You can adjust the workflow to your specific needs but this example will cause the action to run automatically whenever changes are pushed to the master branch. The job can can also be manually triggered.

Now as soon as you commit these changes to the master branch either via a merge commit or a direct push into it, the workflow will run and apply the changes to the database. The neat thing is that it is idempotent so you can run it as many times as you like without fear of breaking things. Liquibase will create two special tables in your database called `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock` to track changes, and limit concurrent access, respectively. There are many features in liquibase which are beyond the scope of this response so have a look at the documentation linked above.

So, if you later add script `003_some_new_table.sql` and then later `004_my_cool_stored_proc.sql` and commit them, the db will reflect these changes shortly after you push to master automatically.
Also, this is a simple approach which requires db passwords to be stored as GitHub secrets. A more sophisticated approach can utilize OIDC integration in github along with access tokens so there are no passwords to maintain anywhere. Alternatively, you may choose to store db credentials in an Azure Key Vault and fetch them in your GitHub action in a step prior to the liquibase action.

Comment: Hm. I am not sure how this answer the initial question. I am not an expert on liquibase too. Can you elaborate?